# Elasticsearch using to filter detailed data out of a bif demand list

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a huge CSV file with three columns:

```
number of product, KindOfProduct, FinalSubmissionTime
```

The data is for a whole month and the `FinalSubmissionTime` is specified with the date and hour. Now I want to use elastic search, to upload make an index and use an aggregation, to split the data into days. Then I want to import it into Python and find the peak hours every day and how many products are due to submit at this hour.

I load my csv into elasticsearch, but I didn't find any way I can split it in buckets of days, without adding all the demand together.

Comment: If `FinalSubmissionTime` was correctly mapped as a `date` field, then you can use a `date_histogram` aggregation with a "day" interval

Comment: What's the exact format of `FinalSubmissionTime`?

Comment: Hello, basically my csv file where i get the data from looks like this: productId,productType,dueDateTime   
1,football,2022-01-01 07:00:00  
2,basketball,2022-01-01 07:00:00  
3,hockeyball,2022-01-01 07:00:00  
4,basketball,2022-01-01 07:00:00  
5,rugbyball,2022-01-01 07:00:00  
6,hockyeball,2022-01-01 08:00:00  
7,football,2022-01-05 12:00:00  
Could you show me how the aggregation would look like ? I need to analyse demand, which i have for every hour of each day in the year. I need to analyse the demand every hour for each day seperatly.

Comment: So i want to use elasticsearch aggregations to group the days in buckets and than use a gurobi linear optimasation model to find out the day with the most demand of maschines (which can only run 6 hours in a day, thats why i cannot add the demand per day together)

Comment: Than what Val suggested earlier should work. You just need to tweak the date format in the mapping to ensure that it is parsed correctly. BTW, if you don't mention  someone in the comment with `@<PersonName>`, they don't get notification and may never come back to your question, especially folks like Val who answer and comment on many questions every day. Click on the Help link on the right of the comment field for more information.